# How can a global logging object be set up in an imported Python module?

Tags: python, logging, module, global

I want to create a global logging object in a Python module that is imported by many small scripts. The Python module is designed to provide a consistent setup of things like logging, logos, timing etc. for all scripts. I'm trying to set up the logging in this module in order to make it easy to change the logging characteristics of all of these scripts at once.

The relevant part of the Python module is as follows:

```
if engageLog:
    global log
    log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logging.root.addHandler(technicolor.ColorisingStreamHandler())
```

How could I write this such that the logging object is available in the scripts *without requiring any setup* beyond importing the module?

In the following example script, the module is called `propyte`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
################################################################################
#                                                                              #
# script-1                                                                     #
#                                                                              #
################################################################################

Usage:
    script-1 [options]

Options:
    -h, --help               display help message
    --version                display version and exit
    -v, --verbose            verbose logging
    -u, --username=USERNAME  username
    --data=FILENAME          input data file [default: data.txt]
"""

name    = "script-1"
version = "2015-10-21T1331Z"

import os
import sys
import time
import docopt

import propyte

def main(options):

    global program
    program = propyte.Program(options = options)

    # access options and arguments
    input_data_filename = options["--data"]

    log.info("")

    log.info("input data file: {filename}".format(
        filename = input_data_filename
    ))

    print("")

    program.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = docopt.docopt(__doc__)
    if options["--version"]:
        print(version)
        exit()
    main(options)
```

Comment: `from propyte import log` doesn't work?

Comment: @riotburn Thanks for your suggestion. The instance of the log object in the module is created within a class in the module (```Program```). When I add the statement ```from propyte import log``` *after* instantiating the ```Program``` object, it does seem to import the log object appropriately. Do you think this is an ok approach?

Comment: As Martijn mentions in his answer below, you can set named loggers which become available globally.  If you are aware of this, outside of fully knowing your use case, you could initiate the logger at the module level of propyte using `getLogger('propyte')` and set your handlers and other settings.  Then in your script, all you have to do is import logging and set `log = logging.getLogger('propyte')` and it will have the same settings as those set in the propyte module.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `log` attribute on the module:

```
import propyte

propyte.log  # the global log object in the propyte module
```

Note however that the `logging` module configuration is already global. You can use `logging.getLogger('somename')` and it'll return a *singleton* logger object associated with that name. Configuration applied to that object will still be present when you retrieve the same logger in another module.